# # is missing in codename one when making call

Tags: codenameone

When making call in codename one application (tested in android), the application is dialing without '#'. How can I correct this? Also I want to make direct call instead of opening Dialer first. Here is a piece of code I have used:

```
Display.getInstance().dial(*100#);
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

We invoke the native dialer intent which removes the # key.

Dialing directly is problematic in most platforms including Android, you can access that for Android only using native interfaces:
http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html